# Form validation with Material UI and multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a form component, which generated a form with the supplied fields. Fields are generated by the use of Material UI. Some fields are required.
At the bottom of the form, I have either

- 2 (submit / cancel) or
- 3 (submit / reject / cancel) buttons.

The `submit` button works fine, if not all required fields are completed, an error is shown on the specific field (thanks to material UI for handeling this). The `cancel` button has its own onClick event, redirecting the user to a specific page.

For the `reject` button, I want to have a different action then the submit button, but I do want to make sure the required fields are filled out (avoiding sending a blank comment field). Generating the button is no problem, including the onClick event.

How do I trigger the form validation provided by material UI on a custom onClick event handler? This will allow me to first validate the form, before executing the custom onClick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) method.

This method returns a `boolean` value, indicating whether the form is valid or not. You can use this method in your custom onClick event handler to check if the form is valid before executing the custom logic.